# Android Layout - Disable unnecessary area

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am creating a custom pop up window for an exit confirmation. For that, I am using a `RelativeLayout` with the properties `layout_width="match_parent"` and `layout_height="match_parent"`.

How can I make the `WebView` area disabled for scrolling and clicking?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/banner_main">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/web"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:minHeight="400dp" />

    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/exit_popup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="#80111111"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#fff"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            app:cardElevation="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
            ads:contentPadding="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="ARE YOU SURE TO EXIT?"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                    android:paddingRight="0dp"
                    android:paddingTop="7dp">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_back"
                        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="18dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Nope"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button_exit"
                        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward"
                        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="18dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Yes"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why not just use a non-cancelable AlertDialog?

Comment: @TheWanderer I want to create more custom style with layout.

Comment: You can do that with AlertDialogs. Just use `setView()`.

Comment: If you want that one. Just disable the `scrollview.setEnabled(false)` when the dialog is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved by add onClick listener on background layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/exit_popup"
        android:onClick="nullMethod"

public void nullMethod(View view) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for disabling all scrolling in webview:

```
disable scroll on touch
webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
  }
});
```

To only hide the scrollbars, add code at the time of you execute popup.

```
 web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id. web); 
 web.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
 web.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

You can also try to wrap your webview with vertically scrolling scrollview and disable all scrolling on the webview:

```
web.setScrollContainer(false);
```